# Why does Scala use `equals` when pattern matching with singleton objects?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

As it turns out, using singleton objects in a pattern match relies on their `equals` method:

```scala
trait Foo

object A extends Foo {
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = false
}

object B extends Foo {
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = true
}

val a: Foo = A
a match {
  case A => "is A"
  case B => "is B"
  case _ => "unknown"
}

// evaluates to "is B"
```

Why not simply use reference equality (`eq`)?

Comment: How is the Scala compiler supposed to know that you don't want to use `equals` in this case? And why is using sometimes `equals` and sometimes something else (such as `eq` here) "simple"?

Comment: "using singleton objects in a pattern match relies on their equals method". Using *anything* in a pattern match relies on the `equals` method.

Comment: @Thilo Pattern matching doesn't rely on `equals` with regular classes. Replace the aforementioned code with classes and it will evaluate to `is A`. That's why I'm confused; why the inconsistency?

Comment: Please show the code with classes. Otherwise it is not clear what `a` is now and what the patterns are.

Comment: @Thilo Pattern matching doesn't _always_ use equals. Matching against symbols uses `equals`, but extractors or type checking would not. For example `case x: A.type`.

Comment: @MichaelZajac. Right, I meant "matching against symbols" (as shown in the question). That's why we need to see the other pattern with classes that seem to cause confusion. Something like `case x: ClassA` does something very much different (it checks `instanceof`, which is also not `eq`). I'd like to see where `eq` is being used.

Comment: @Thilo `==` uses both `eq` and `equals` (to avoid matching `null` mostly), so `equals` is really being used because of `==`

Comment: @Thilo I see your point now. As @MichaelZajac pointed out, the code shown in the question "matches against symbols" (same as `case 1 =>`), which is not the same as `case _: A.type =>` (which is what I was referring to when saying that pattern matching doesn't rely on `equals` with regular classes). I guess the cause for my confusion then is the difference in syntax for expressing the type of either a class or an object.

Comment: The distinction isn't between object and class, it's between a stable value (singleton object, literal, variable) and a type (class, trait, etc.).